# Compact IRI with an empty string prefix: can it be done?

Tags: json-ld

In many of the Linked Data and Semantic Network languages such as TURTLE, there is support for namespacing of IRIs.

```
@prefix foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>

<#me> foaf:name "Cort Ammon" .
```

That's using TURTLE notation.  the `foaf:name` gets resolved to `http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/name`.

JSON-LD has the same functionality:

```
{
    "@context" {
        "foaf": "http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/"
    },
    "@id": "#me",
    "foaf:name": "Cort Ammon"
}
```

I am looking to use the empty-string prefix, to create IRIs like `:name` or `:foo`.  In TURTLE this can be done with

```
@prefix : <some/absolute/IRI>
```

However, JSON does not permit the empty string to be used as a term (because it may not be usable in all languages).  I can't do the natural

```
{
    "@context" {
        "": "some/absolute/IRI"
    },
    ...
}
```

Is there a way to use this empty-string prefix in JSON-LD?

Comment: Specifying a default prefix-less vocabulary wouldn’t work for you? (i.e., using `name` instead of `:name`)

Comment: @unor I might have to, if that's the best JSON-LD can do, but I'd prefer not to.  The rationale is user experience.  I'm designing software which will be used by people who don't yet understand semantic networks, so I'm creating a namespace which means "The names in this namespace are *just* syntax, and have no semantic meaning associated with them" for people who are used to just typing names and assuming the human reading them knows what they're talking about.  I want just enough syntax to make them ponder what might be lurking underneath.

Comment: Your comment does encourage me to think of other symbologies, like using @base and `#name` which might be able to convey my pragmatic intent.  But it still does baffle me that JSON-LD might not be able to handle `:name` which that sort of construct is a staple for tutorials on semantic information, not to mention appearing in plenty of non-semantic systems like XML namespaces.

Answer (score 3):

This is something that we could re-visit for 1.1, as I believe all languages are now capable of handling JSON keys that are empty strings.

In fact, if you try your example using "" instead of "foaf" on the JSON-LD playground, it will expand properly. The JavaScript implementation enforces the normative requirement that terms not be empty strings, and so gives an error when trying to use such a context to compact, but my own Ruby implementation does not seem to place such a restriction, as you can see by trying it [here](http://rdf.greggkellogg.net/distiller?command=compact&format=jsonld&output_format=jsonld), as the API algorithm does not specifically call for such an error.

input:

```
[
  {
    "@id": "https://json-ld.org/playground/#me",
    "http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/name": [
      {
        "@value": "Cort Ammon"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

context:

```
{
  "@context": {"": "http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/"}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution to achieve basically the same is to use [`@vocab`](https://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld/#default-vocabulary). Your Turtle example would be translated to

```
{
    "@context" {
        "@vocab": "some/absolute/IRI"
    },
    "@id": "#me",
    "name": "Cort Ammon"
}
```

Note how `name` doesn't have a prefix.